# Create Variables from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script that I want to import a CSV and create separate variables. One for WindowsKey and the other for OfficeKey

CSV Will look like:

```
School, WindowsKey, OfficeKey
Saints, BBBB-BBBB, XXXX-XXXX
Bears, YYYY-YYYY, ZZZZ-ZZZZ
```

Part of the Script:

```
$School = "Saints"
(Import-Csv k:\Keys.csv) | Where-Object {$_.School -eq $School}
```

This will make a table that looks like this:

```
School    : Saints
WindowsKey: BBBB-BBBB
OfficeKey : XXXX-XXXX
```

How do I go about putting `WindowsKey` and `OfficeKey` into a variable that I can use later on in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv k:\keys.csv | Where-Object {$_.School -eq $School}
```

then you can access the data by dot notation, for example

```
$csv.WindowsKey
```

note that the properties contain arrays and not string data if you select multiple values so you will have to loop through it

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (if you want to be able to access all keys by school) would be to create 2 hashtables for Windows and Office keys:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'K:\Keys.csv'

$windowsKeys = @{}
$officeKeys  = @{}
$csv | % {
  $windowsKeys[$_.School] = $_.WindowsKey
  $officeKeys[$_.School]  = $_.OfficeKey
}
```

Then you can access the keys for each school like this:

```
$school = 'Bears'
"Windows Key ({0}): {1}" -f $school, $windowsKeys[$school]
"Office Key ({0}):  {1}" -f $school, $officeKeys[$school]
```